Determining libraries implementing #[serde(default)]
How can you tell whether a package that implements serde (e.g. serde_json, bincode, postcard) supports the flag #[serde(default)]?
I was surprised that not all packages do.

There isn't a lot you can do. Look at docs and sourcecode.

Yes, I was hoping for direction as to where to look or what to search for. It seems an ecosystem failure if you can't find out whether a library supports certain feature.

Just to verify, do you want to know what serde-deserializable types have #[serde(default)] as one of their fields? Or do you want to know what types you can use #serde(default)] on? The latter is the Default trait. The former is an implementation detail.

I want to know what serde libraries support using the trait #[serde(default)]. E.g. serde_json does, bincode does not.

@Test Any type implementing Default can be used with #[serde(default)] so this question doesn't really have much to do with serde. Note if a type doesn't implement Default you can still provide a default for a field of that type yourself using #[serde(default = "foo")] which will call foo() to obtain the default value for the field: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b457046518c76f093e4fd99a2d88bebc

"I was surprised that not all packages do" - could you provide an example? This sounds rather strange, to be honest.

Serde serialization formats can be divided into self-describing formats (like JSON) and non-self-describing formats (like bincode). Self-describing formats store not only the data, but also information about the structure of the data. This allows you to make deserialization dependent on the structure of the data instead of just the data itself.
Many attributes, including #[serde(default)] and also #[serde(untagged)], require self-describing formats. In order to use default, the format needs to know when there are missing fields, which is structural information.
So ideally, serde formats will be documented to indicate whether they are self-describing or not. When this isn't the case, trying it out and looking for errors is a quick way, and if you need something more certain, reading the format's specification or implementation of Deserializer will give you more information.
